# Flutter, How to create a clickable bar in a BarChart widget?

Tags: flutter, charts, bar-chart

I have a **flutter** App and need a [Bar chart](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/bar_charts/simple.html) in which I can **click** bars to open new page with related information. **How should I do it?**

[image]

```
/// Bar chart example
charts.BarChart(
    createSampleData(),
    animate: true,
    barGroupingType: charts.BarGroupingType.stacked,
    barRendererDecorator:
        new charts.BarLabelDecorator<String>(),
    domainAxis: new charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(),
  ),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `selectionModels` array property of `BarChart` Widget:

```
new charts.BarChart(
     createSampleData(),
     animate: true,
     barGroupingType: charts.BarGroupingType.stacked,
     selectionModels: [
       new charts.SelectionModelConfig(
         type: charts.SelectionModelType.info,
         changedListener: _onSelectionChanged,
       )
     ],
     barRendererDecorator:
         new charts.BarLabelDecorator<String>(),
     domainAxis: new charts.OrdinalAxisSpec(),
  ),

_onSelectionChanged(charts.SelectionModel model) {
    final selectedDatum = model.selectedDatum;

    if (selectedDatum.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        print(selectedDatum.first.datum.sales);
      });
    }
  }
```